# Sentry React Native Crash - Native Client is not available, can't start on native

Tags: android, react-native, sentry

I am getting crash on app launch in android with below error.

> **Native Client is not available, can't start on native.**

```
Sentry.init({
        enableNative: true,
        enableNativeCrashHandling: true,
        dsn:
            'https://xyx.com/sentry/12',
      })
```

When I set enableNative: false, then the crash stops coming but the android related crashes are not logged in sentry.

I have added sentry in build.gradle as well as per the sentry integration doc.

Any solution for this?

Comment: compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are both 30? mine occurs if they are 30 and 29 are ok,

Comment: Do you use expo? Their managed builds are not supporting native reporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem as well, using the test of Sentry.nativeCrash() - the application would crash, but not be reported.

To fix, set autoInitializeNativeSdk to false and initialize in the AndroidManifest.

```
Sentry.init({
    autoInitializeNativeSdk: false,
    dsn:
        'https://xyx.com/sentry/12',
  })
```

Initialize the AndroidSDK in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.auto-init" tools:replace="android:value" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.dsn" android:value="https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0" />
</application>
```

Make sure you add  `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your manifest.

Follow the below link for documentation.
[Native Initialize](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/manual-setup/native-init/#android-configuration)